# How to use Lombok's RequiredArgsConstructor with Nullaway?

Tags: java, lombok, non-nullable, java-annotations, nullaway

We're trying to add "Nullaway" (https://github.com/uber/NullAway) to our repo. This is a tool that assumes everything not annotated with @Nullable can't be null and enforces it in compile time.

We also use Lombok, with focus on @Data. Lombok decides which fields to add to the RequiredArgsConstructor based on a @NonNull annotation. Furthermore, Nullaway requires that all constructurs set a value to all the fields not marked as @Nullable.

Our issue is - we don't wish to annotate all fields (both with @Nonnull and @Nullable), as it's redundant. We'd like to have one of them be a "default" (preferably the @Nonnull option).

How can we solve this? An ideal solution would be to configure the RequiredArgsConstructor to treat any field not marked as @Nullable as required, but that option doesn't exist. We're open to any and all creative ideas.

I tried looking for such a configuration in Lombok, which doesn't exist. I also tried annotating at the class level to no avail.

Comment: From the docs: "@RequiredArgsConstructor generates a constructor with 1 parameter for each field that requires special handling. All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared."

Essentially what I'd like to do is change what it means to "require special handling".

https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: Did you read [this section](https://github.com/uber/NullAway#lombok) of the NullAway readme?

Answer (score 0):

Make a text file and name it `lombok.config`. Inside, stick some lines of text. See [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration#addNullAnnotations) of the feature. You can tell lombok about your nullable annotations. You can also tell it to add `@Generated` annotations which [NullAway understands](https://github.com/uber/NullAway#lombok) - thanks to @Sweeper who linked to that section of the NullAway docs in the comments.

lombok.config can be in a package, or any parent directory of it; even `/` / `C:\` though that'd perhaps be a bit weird. Generally you'd put this either in `projectroot` or `projectroot/src`.